# C# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString' is not enumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model, ienumerable

Here is the context : 
This is my first ASP.NET MVC web application. 
On the categories list, I click on a category to see all infos about it in a new view.
From this view, I display its name, its description and the number of products in this category.
Below that, I want to display all products in this category.
I gave a try to the `Html.Action()` method.
But when I want to iterate through the `foreach` statement, Visual Studio tells me that `Type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString' is not enumerable`.

Here is my view (details about a category):

```
@model UlysseCMS.Models.category

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details about "+ Model.category_name + " category";
    var nbProducts = Html.Action("GetNumberOfProductByCategory", "Product", Model.category_id);
    var productsList = Html.Action("GetListOfProductsByCategory", "Product", Model.category_id);
}

<div>
    <span class="leader">
        <span class="mif-chevron-thin-right fg-teal"></span>
        <span>@Html.ActionLink("Categories", "Index")</span> 
        <span class="mif-chevron-thin-right fg-teal"></span>
        <span>@Model.category_name</span>
        <span class="mif-chevron-right fg-teal"></span>
        <span>details</span>
    </span>
</div>
<br />
<hr class="bg-teal" />
<br />

<div class="margin30">
    <div class="flex-grid">
        <div class="row cells7">
            <div class="cell colspan3 offset1 sub-header">
                Category name :
            </div>
            <div class="cell colspan4">
                @Model.category_name
            </div>
        </div> <br/>
        <div class="row cells7">
            <div class="cell colspan3 offset1 sub-header">
                Category description :
            </div> <br/>
            <div class="cell colspan4">
                @Model.category_description
           </div>
        </div> <br/>
        <div class="row cells7">
            <div class="cell colspan3 offset1 sub-header">
                Number of products in this category :
            </div>
            <div class="cell colspan4">
                @nbProducts
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@foreach (var item in productsList)
{

}
```

Here is my `GetListOfProductsByCategory()` method from the `ProductController` :

```
public IEnumerable<product> GetListOfProductsByCategory(int id)
{
    return db.product.Where(x => x.product_category_id == id);
}
```

I still continue to find a solution with `IEnumerable` casting or something.

Thanks,

Hellcat.

Comment: How you are getting productsList in your view?

Comment: html.Action return MvcHtmlString

Comment: Your action should rerun ActionResult I mean a partial view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of @Html.Action is a View.
When you have an action inside a controller, this action usually return a view, and that rendered view is result of Html.Action ,for displaying it you need to use an @ before html.
You should write your code as below:

```
public ActionResult GetListOfProductsByCategory(int id)
{
    return View(db.product.Where(x => x.product_category_id == id));
}
```

Then right click on View and from menu select Add View, then create a partial view.
inside partial view you can enumerate your list and create the rendered out put.
Finally wherever you want to show the rendered list, just call:

```
@Html.Action("GetListOfProductsByCategory",id)
```

When creating view, you need to select your model and view type as list so on top of your view you would have:

```
@model IEnumerable<product>
```

Then you must use you foreach as below:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. However, my problem is not solved. Indeed, I don't understand how you can iterate through the list of products returned to the partial view (in ProductController) from the view (in CategoryController) ? Even with these modifications, I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I modified my Partial View (GetListOfProductsByCategory) like that :

```
@model IEnumerable<UlysseCMS.Models.product>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id = item.product_id })">
        <div class="tile tile-wide bg-white block-shadow margin30" data-role="tile">
            <div class="tile-content slide-up-2">
                <div class="slide fg-darkTeal">
                    <span class="sub-leader" style="padding-left: 5px;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.product_name)</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
}
```

And in my Category Details View I display the products like this :

```
@Html.Action("GetListOfProductsByCategory", "Product", Model.category_id)
```

It's now okay hanks to Mehrdad Babaki's answer.